# Python @property does not work as I want it to

Tags: python, properties

I am having a small code that define a class with one property. Then when I expect in the main program for the prints, they don't happen and the result for the above code is '5':

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        print 'getter'
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print 'setter'
        self._x = x


def main():
    C.x = 5
    print C.x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My question is what can I do to make this code print the 'getter' and the 'setter'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd use `C` properly (ie create an instance of it) you will get what you expect:

```
c = C()
c.x = 5
print(c.x)
```

outputs

```
setter
getter
5
```

Comment: Oh, huh, they've got that problem too. They do also need to inherit from `object`, though; the `print` syntax indicates they're on Python 2.

Comment: If I use it like this there is an overhead?

Comment: @YotamHammer: Overhead compared to what? The code you've posted that doesn't work? Don't compare the performance of correct code and wrong code; you can do anything as fast as you want if you're fine with doing it wrong.

Comment: You are right, is there a more convenient way to change the behavior of the setters and the getters of objects?